# MySQL database error using scrapy

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I am trying to save scrapped data in MySQL database. My script.py is

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import unidecode
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html


class ElementSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'books'
    download_delay = 3
    allowed_domains = ["goodreads.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/19793.I_Marked_My_Calendar_For_This_Book_s_Release",]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="next_page"]',)), callback="parse", follow= True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@id="all_votes"]/table[@class="tableList js-dataTooltip"]/tr/td[2]/div[@class="js-tooltipTrigger tooltipTrigger"]/a/@href'):       
            full_url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            print full_url
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback = self.parse_books)
            break;


        next_page = response.xpath('.//a[@class="next_page"]/@href').extract()
        if next_page:
            next_href = next_page[0]
            next_page_url = 'https://www.goodreads.com' + next_href
            print next_page_url
            request = scrapy.Request(next_page_url, self.parse)
            yield request

    def parse_books(self, response):
        yield{
            'url': response.url,
            'title':response.xpath('//div[@id="metacol"]/h1[@class="bookTitle"]/text()').extract(),
            'link':response.xpath('//div[@id="metacol"]/h1[@class="bookTitle"]/a/@href').extract(),
        }
```

And pipeline.py is

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html


import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

from scrapy.http import Request
import sys

class SQLStore(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","books" )
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        print "connected to DB"

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print "hi"

        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO books_data(next_page_url) VALUES (%s)""", (item['url']))
            self.conn.commit()

        except Exception, e:
            print e
```

When i run the script there is no error. Spider running well but I think cursor not points to process_item. Even it not print hi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature is wrong, it should take item and spider parameters:

```
process_item(self, item, spider)
```

Also you need to have the pipeline setup in your *settings.py* file:

```
 ITEM_PIPELINES = {"project_name.path.SQLStore"}
```

Your  syntax is also incorrect, you need to pass a tuple:

```
  self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO books_data(next_page_url) VALUES (%s)""", 
    (item['url'],) # <- add ,
```

Comment: Already have tried this but not working. I added pipeline in setting.py like this `ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'test1.pipelines.SQLStore': 300,
}`

Comment: What is in your init.py file in your piplines directory? Also do you have `process_item(self, item, spider)`?

Comment: Then how does scrapy find your SQLStore pipeline?

Comment: I mean is your file actually called pipeline or pipelines? You have *pipeline* in your question and *pipelines* above. Also where do you yield any items?

Comment: well look at my pipeline.py when I print something inside `def __init__(self): ` and when i print inside `def process_item(self):` it prints nothing. means `def process_item(self):` not callable.

Comment: `def process_item(self):` is wrong as I already pointed out.  You also never yield an item so what is `item['next_page_url']` even supposed to get?

Comment: i make changes in question above. please suggest now.

Comment: Why are you breaking after one loop?

Comment: It is just for testing so i am breaking it.

Comment: @V.Khakhil, the code works once you have, `process_item(self, item, spider)`,  `ITEM_PIPELINES` configured correctly and pass a tuple as value in your insert statement and you actually have passed the correct  username, password etc.. to connect to your database. Add the print before you  `MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","books" )`

Comment: Once I  only want print hi inside `process_item(self, item, spider)`  but it not working. yes `def __init__(self):` working i tested it.

Comment: @V.Khakhil, it is working if you have done it correctly, as I commented above put the print before you connect to the database and right after to see if the pipeline is getting called and it is not an error connecting to the db that is causing the issue. Also add  the log output `Enabled item pipelines:`.

Comment: In both case before and after `MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","books" )` print command works.

Comment: Then the pipeline is working, your code errors in the insert regardless which if you `print(e)` you can see

Comment: This is the output- D:\xampp\htdocs\py\test1>scrapy crawl section1 -L WARNING
connected to DB
https://www.goodreads.com/genres/list?page=2
https://www.goodreads.com/genres/list?page=3
https://www.goodreads.com/genres/list?page=4

Comment: What is section1?

Comment: section1 is spider name--- i run it using scrapy crawl section1

Comment: But your spiders name is books? Also have you fixed the sql error?

Comment: sorry i have changed the spider name and there is no error shows in sql.

Comment: Just correct the sql, add a trailing comma. The pipeline is 100 percent working if you can see output when you print in the class.